# Identify points close to a line

Tags: qgis, distance

Scenario
Layer 1 : shapefile lines representing roads
Layer 2 : shapefile points representing remarkable trees

Of course, the trees are not on the roads.
I want to identify the number of trees that are close to each roads, i.e. at less then say 5 meters.

QGIS 3.16.16
I tested a virtual field with

```sql
aggregate(layer:= 'trees' ,
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:="treeid",
    filter:=distance($geometry, geometry(@parent) <5))
```

syntax is accepted but it returns 0, even if i change the 5 by 10, 100 or 1000

What's wrong with this logic?

Comment: what projection are your trees in? - I'd probably buffer the roads and join by location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misplaced closing parenthesis, meaning you are passing `geometry(@parent) < 5` as an argument to `distance`.

```sql
aggregate(layer:='trees',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:="treeid",
    filter:=distance($geometry, geometry(@parent)) < 5 -- move < 5 outside the distance function
)
```