# Copy only field between different vector layers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, buffer, expression

I have a line layer, which I have created a buffer polygon layer from to count points in close distance.

I now want the output of that count back in my line layer.
How do I get the column in my old layer? I want to be able to delete the buffer layer afterwards, so a simple attribute join/connect is not possible.

I thought about a field generator approach, but I can't find the correct expressions to grab info out of a different layer. The layers obviously have the same objects with the same attributes, also a unique ID.

So I am looking for an expression to copy my field from my polygon layer to my line layer by ID.

Im am on QGIS 3.22.3 on Windows 10

Comment: You can use a Field Calculator expression, such as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424398/128665). You would calculate this on a field in your line layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new layer by joining two (and join whatever attributes you need), based on one attribute, like a unique identifier that previously should exist on your original layer. Then from processing toolbox (gear icon on toolbar) select "Join attributes by field value" algorithm and fill in the appropriate values and execute.

Obviously your unique identifier will serve as the joining criteria.